# optimizing ffmpeg in windows platform for processing with web-cam

Tags: java, ffmpeg, video-streaming, webcam, video-processing

I have to develop a tool in java that will capture frames from webcam, Now what I have done for that is, I have used **Runtime** class to run **ffmpeg** and other commands, when it starts capturing frames from my **web-cam**, 
I am using following method for that.

```
public class FFMPEGClass {

    private String ffmpegExeLocation, line;
    private final String FRAME_DIGITS = "010";

    public FFMPEGClass(String capturingDName, String outputImagesLocation, int framesPerSecond) {
        ffmpegExeLocation = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\bin\\";
        System.out.println(ffmpegExeLocation);
        try {            
            System.out.println(ffmpegExeLocation + "ffmpeg -t 100000 "
                    + "-f vfwcap -s 640x480 -i 0 -r 1/" + framesPerSecond + " -f image2 " + outputImagesLocation + "\\camera%"+FRAME_DIGITS+"d.jpg");
            Process pp = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(ffmpegExeLocation + "ffmpeg -t 100000 "
                    + "-f vfwcap -s 640x480 -i 0 -r 1/" + framesPerSecond + " -f image2 " + outputImagesLocation + "\\camera%"+FRAME_DIGITS+"d.jpg");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pp.getErrorStream()));
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                 System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

In my case **capturingDName** is **USB2.0 UVC VGA WebCam**
**outputImagesLocation** is **e:\myfolder\frames\** and
**framesPerSecond** is **10**

This code works well but it is unable to capture frames efficiently, In other words I want to say that its processing is very slow, can anyone please tell that how can I optimize it so that it can capture frames very fastly.

I have **Intel Core i3** processor with **6 GB** of **RAM**

**I have already checked many answers from google and stackoverflow but these are not working in my case**

Comment: down voters, or people who will wish to close this question, kindly **dare** to put your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use 10 fro `frameperseconds`, the following call

```
Process pp = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(ffmpegExeLocation + "ffmpeg -t 100000 "
                    + "-f vfwcap -s 640x480 -i 0 -r 1/" + framesPerSecond + " -f image2 " + outputImagesLocation + "\\camera%"+FRAME_DIGITS+"d.jpg");
```

will expand to something like :

```
ffmpeg -t 100000 -f vfwcap -s 640x480 -i 0 -r 1/10 -f image2 output%05d.jpg
```

The way you use the `-r`option is wrong (see [ffmpeg doc](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html%5d)), if you want 10 frame per second, update your code to remove the fractional!

```
Process pp = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(ffmpegExeLocation + "ffmpeg -t 100000 "
                        + "-f vfwcap -s 640x480 -i 0 -r " + framesPerSecond + " -f image2 " + outputImagesLocation + "\\camera%"+FRAME_DIGITS+"d.jpg");
```

Comment: I am using code provided by you, but when i am using it first time then it is not opening the web-cam for processing,

Comment: what do you mean by "1st time"? does it mean that another (2nd) run work ? can you test the command line out of your program and update your question with a copy of your terminal output (to see ffmpeg version etc...) ?

Comment: I am using netbeans as IDE when i am running my code using the command suggested by you then it opens a simple system call that asks to select web-cam from a dropdown list but it does not opens the web-cam.

Comment: I am getting this ERROR check this link for error snapshot (https://www.dropbox.com/s/pkmeel8xhpsg7l3/error.png)

Comment: so list your devices and see the devices you have : ffmpeg -y -f vfwcap -i list

Comment: I have already done this too, this was the first thing that i did for my work. :)

Comment: I asked that because, in the error snapshot you posted, the message is just saying that you don't have a device 0. So in that case I don't understand how your program may have work a day as  you use "-i 0" in the command you call. As far as i understand, with -r 1/10, it works but with poor performance (missing frame), and with -r 10, the command popup a selection window and fails, and you cannot start a capture out of your own soft.... it's really crazy !

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36073/discussion-between-alexbuisson-and-user2320537)